# uiwebview going fullscreen automatically when loading page with strict multimedia

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I created a uitableview with a uiwebview that loads a webpage that goes directly to the link of a multimedia file, but I don't want it to automatically go fullscreen. Simply load it and then allow the user to play it and then go fullscreen if he wants.

Comment: You don't want the webpage to go fullscreen, or you don't want the media file being played within the webpage to go full screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant do that using UIWebView, what you can do, is to change the link to an image that contains an play button overlay image (like youtube does) and then when the user clicks on that image, start playing the video.